# How do we get to another stronghold in minecraft without using cheats?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

so me and my boyfriend were playing minecraft and threw several eye of enders which led us to a stronghold that only consisted of one room, so we tried to mine all around it up and down and couldn't find any ender portal near it or in it and after doing research online we found that our best choice was to head to the second stronghold in the world out of the 3 and see which one has the ender portal, but the eye of ender only leads to the same one no matter how far we go, so we can't use that as a guide to any of the others. Is there any easy way that we can get to a different stronghold without having to use cheats? We are playing on xbox 1 and playstation.

Answer (score 1):

If you know seed - [search tool](https://www.chunkbase.com/apps/stronghold-finder) (choose right edition)
It is unlikely that there is no portal in stronghold, maybe check again digging up and down around spot that ender eye marked.
Otherwise another one can be 5000 blocks away in any direction, so you have to keep trying - like 2000 blocks away, which can be really long journey.

Comment: We looked it up and other people have had the same problem of finding a stronghold and it only consisting of 1 or 2 rooms and nothing else around it. It is rare, but the main thing that was directed to do was to travel to a different stronghold, so that's why we're trying to do that. Haven't found it yet but thanks for the website!